# React + Redux + Thunk: multiple hooks on the same event

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I've got stuck with a problem of hook reusage when state and redux store should work together. I've simplified a code to show the problem.

There is a component where I want to use multiple hooks (for simplicity I re-use `useMouseDown` hook here):

```
export function Counter() {
  const count = useSelector(selectCount);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const plusSighRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);

  useMouseDown({
    ref: plusSighRef,
    onMouseDown: () => {
      console.log('in first hook');
      dispatch(increment());
    }
  });

  useMouseDown({
    ref: plusSighRef,
    onMouseDown: () => { console.log('in second hook'); }
  });

  return <button ref={plusSighRef}>+</button>;
}
```

Each hook has inner state and has own callback on mouse down event:

```
const useMouseDown = ({ ref, onMouseDown }) => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const element = ref.current;

    const down = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      setIsClicked(true);
      onMouseDown(e);
    }
    element.addEventListener('mousedown', down);

    return (): void => {
      element.removeEventListener('mousedown', down);
    };
  }, [onMouseDown, ref]);
}
```

As a result a mousedown event in second hook is never triggered. The problem is that re-render occurs earlier than second hook is started.

I found some solutions but don't like both:

1. use something like `setTimeout(() => dispatch(increment()), 0)` inside the first hook mousedown prop. But it seems to be not obvious in terms of re-usage.
2. rewrite two hooks into one and manipulate with one "big" mousedown handler. But in that case a combined hook could be difficult for maintaining.

So I need a solution that allow to retain structure as is (I mean two separate hooks), but has second hook is working too. Could someone help how to get it?

Comment: Why not to define two functions that would handle your logic and then fire them in one hook?

Comment: Yes, i thought about that. the main idea is that first and second hook are different in terms of logic. I mean, for example, that first hook should be responsible for mouse click and the second hook should be responsible for dragging. So...it would be great to use them separately somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just keep your logic in two different functions and execute it sequentially in the hook's `onMouseDown` function?

```
const executeFirstFlow = () => {
  console.log('in first function');
  dispatch(increment());
};

const executeSecondFlow = () => {
  console.log('in second function');
};

useMouseDown({
    ref: plusSighRef,
    onMouseDown: () => {
        executeFirstFlow();
        executeSecondFlow();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think about this solution, it's absolutely working, but the main idea is that first and second hook are different in terms of logic. I mean, for example, that first hook should be responsible for mouse click and the second hook should be responsible for dragging. So...it would be great to use them separately somewhere.